# Bootstrap 3.3.7 hidden-xs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
                <div class="col-md-6 hidden-xm hidden-sm">
                <div class="col-md-12 hidden-xm"><h3>ההזמנה שלך</h3></div>
                <div class="col-md-12 hidden-xm">
                    <div class="table-responsive hidden-xm">
                        <table class="table table-default">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="text-right">סה"כ</th>
                                    <th class="text-right">מוצר</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                    $totalPrice = 0;
                                    $arr = [];
                                    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product){
                                        $productDetails = get_product($product['id']);
                                        array_push($arr,$product['amount']." x".$productDetails->get_name());
                                        $totalPrice+= $productDetails->get_price()*$product['amount'];
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-right"> <?php echo $productDetails->get_price()*$product['amount']; ?>$</td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><?php echo $productDetails->get_name()." <b>".$product['amount']."x</b>"; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php };?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="total_price">משלוח</td>
                                    <td>9$</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-right total_price">סה"כ</td>
                                    <td class="text-right"> <?php echo $totalPrice+9 ?>$</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 hidden-xm text-right"> אחריות מלאה על המוצרים ל-28 יום</div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="products" value="<?php echo implode("<br>",$arr) ?>">
                    <div class="text-left">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-pay" value="שליחת הזמנה">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I've tried for pretty long time to find out why the : hidden-xm/hidden-sm not working for me. Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong?

also I want to notice that this div is inside a bigger container but I want to hide it if its at a mobile point of view.

Comment: can you include the css of the element that you want to hide using those classes !

Comment: Its Bootstrap, its says on the topic.
why would u unvote the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'ts `hidden-xs` instead of `hidden-xm`

Comment: rofl, cant belive that made me lose my mind for such a long time... such a rookie mistake.